# Force scope bar below UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, scope, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController, everything works great but my scope selector displays beside the text field instead of below it. I know that this is the expected action when the device is in landscape, but since I have the UISearchBar in the master view of a UISplitViewController it ends up looking like this:

[image: UISearchBar problem]

Is there any way to force the scope bar to display below the text field in all interface orientations (I know that this works nicely in Mail.app on the iPad, so its possibly, but who knows if Apple decided to hide the option to do so)

Comment: I found a way to do it, but it isn't a public API.

[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setCombinesLandscapeBars:NO];

Be sure to call it on the searchDisplayController's searchBar and not the UISearchBar itself. Apparently the search display controller is managing this property.

Comment: I am having the same problem and setCombinesLandscapeBars:NO indeed solved the problem, but also Apple's sample "TableSearch" gets the same results without using that method. Did you found another solution?

Comment: In case you are not rejected your could use this code, throws no warnings and safe in case apple's engineers decide that private method will be not available any more. 

if ([self.searchDisplayController.searchBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setCombinesLandscapeBars:)]) {
objc_msgSend(self.searchDisplayController.searchBar, @selector(setCombinesLandscapeBars:), NO );}

Comment: Anyone got away using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not part of the public API. Hopefully it will be added in the future. It can be accomplished using Private APIs, looking through a UIKit class dump will help you there.

Good luck!

edit: Note that using private APIs can get you rejected from the app store, as most people already know.

Answer (score 2):

I used the UISearchDisplayDelegate to show and hide the scope bar.

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [controller.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [controller.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use private APIs. Instead, follow Apple's recommendation from IOS User Interface Guidelines:

> When a search bar is present, a scope bar can appear near it. The
>   scope bar displays below the search bar, regardless of orientation,
>   unless you use a search display controller in your code (for more
>   information on the way this works, see UISearchDisplayController Class
>   Reference). When you use a search display controller, the scope bar is
>   displayed within the search bar to the right of the search field when
>   the device is in landscape orientation (in portrait orientation, it’s
>   below the search bar).

This worked for me using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set up your search bar programattically?  Here's what I'm using on my current project.  It hides the search bar until the user scrolls up, and the scope bar is loaded below the text field when they start typing items.  From there just filter as usual:

```
- (void)setupSearchBar {
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Users", @"Groups", nil];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar
                                                          contentsController:self];
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
}
```

call `[self setupSearchBar];` in viewDidLoad you're off to the races.